# Export Woocommerce data to Google Spreadsheet (Wrong price format)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, woocommerce, export, hook-woocommerce

The Woocommerce export to a Google Spreadsheet with the code below works. Except the format of the order total shows "99.95" instead of "99,95". This results in some faults in further processing the data. Is there a solution to fix this inside the Apps Script?

In short: The dot needs to be a comma automatically.

```
//this is a function that fires when the webapp receives a GET request
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("request received");
}

//this is a function that fires when the webapp receives a POST request
function doPost(e) {
  var myData             = JSON.parse([e.postData.contents]);
  var order_created      = myData.date_created;
  var billing_email      = myData.billing.email;
  var order_total        = myData.total;
  var order_number       = myData.number;
  var billing_first_name = myData.billing.first_name;
  var billing_last_name = myData.billing.last_name;
  var shipping_country = myData.shipping.country;
  var payment_method = myData.payment_method_title;
  var billing_phone = myData.billing.phone;
  var shipping_address_1 = myData.shipping.address_1;
  var shipping_postcode = myData.shipping.postcode;
  var shipping_city = myData.shipping.city;

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.appendRow([order_number,order_created,order_total,billing_first_name,billing_last_name,billing_email,billing_phone,shipping_address_1,shipping_city,shipping_postcode,shipping_country,payment_method]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Automatically change the "." to ",".

I have limited access with Woocommerce that you are using. Instead I have just created a simple code that will automatically change it on Google Apps Script.

### Sample Code:

```
function stringCleanser (cleansedData){

var cleansedData = cleansedData.toString().replace(/\./g, ",");// Converts it to string, then replace "." with ","
return cleansedData;
}
```

you can use this to call the function whenever needed. I.E. `stringCLeanser(order_total)`; this should automatically create your desired output.

### Test Run:

[image]

### References:

[ToString](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_string.asp#:%7E:text=Definition%20and%20Usage,string%20object%20into%20a%20string.)

[Replace](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)

Answer (score 0):

By default, culture-specific formatting defaults are based [on the spreadsheet's locale](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats). My experience with the Sheets API is very limited, but you should be able to update the properties value directly through the `var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()` resource (default is "en_US").

From the [docs](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#spreadsheetproperties):

> The locale of the spreadsheet in one of the following formats:
>
> - an ISO 639-1 language code such as en
> - an ISO 639-2 language code such as fil, if no 639-1 code exists
> - a combination of the ISO language code and country code, such as en_US

Or, do it directly in your POST (format patterns are at the link I included above):

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
sheet.getRange('D:D').setNumberFormat('0,00'); // assuming order total is column D

// append as usual...
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, see code below;

```
    // This is a function that fires when the web app receives a GET request
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("request received");
}

// This is a function that fires when the web app receives a POST request
function doPost(e) {
  var myData = JSON.parse([e.postData.contents]);
  var order_created = myData.date_created;
  var billing_email = myData.billing.email;
  var order_total = (parseFloat(myData.total).toFixed(2)).replace('.', ',');
  var order_number = myData.number;
  var billing_first_name = myData.billing.first_name;
  var billing_last_name = myData.billing.last_name;
  var shipping_country = myData.shipping.country;
  var billing_phone = myData.billing.phone;
  var shipping_address_1 = myData.shipping.address_1;
  var shipping_postcode = myData.shipping.postcode;
  var shipping_city = myData.shipping.city;

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.appendRow([
    order_number,
    order_created,
    order_total,
    billing_first_name,
    billing_last_name,
    billing_email,
    billing_phone,
    shipping_address_1,
    shipping_city,
    shipping_postcode,
    shipping_country
  ]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting. I'm glad your issue was resolved.If any of the answers above have helped you come up with the solution. please click the accept button on the left (check icon) and upvoting the answer.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).